# Бывают ли утренние сумерки?

Tags: значение-слов

Слово "сумерки" всегда ассоциируется именно с закатом, причем, как в прямом, так и в переносном смысле, вспомним, например, Ницше "Сумерки богов", то есть, закат, падение. Но при этом открываем словарь на сайте Глоссарий.ru и читаем: "Утренние сумерки - промежуток времени от момента прекращения полной темноты до видимого восхода Солнца". То есть, оказывается, сумерки могут быть и утренними. Выходит, что это, так сказать, не процесс, а состояние.
Но смеркаться может только вечером, так? Или утром тоже?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ИЗ СЛОВАРЕЙ

СУМРАК - неполная темнота, полумрак. СУМЕРКИ - полумрак перед заходом солнца и наступлением ночи, а также перед восходом солнца.

СУМЕРКИ - исконное слово, префикс. форма от несохранившегося "мерки", Также диал. меркоть (сумрак, сумерки).Родственные слова: меркнуть, мерцать, мрак, морок, морочить. Интересно, что нем. Morgen и англ. moning также связываются с и.-е. корнем mer, составляющим о.-с. основу morkъ.

Таким образом, утренние сумерки ВОЗМОЖНЫ, что видно из следующих примеров:

1) Солнце выплеснуло на ржаво-зеленую вершину высокой горы озерцо золотого огня, и утренний сумрак ущелья вспыхнул, зарумянился и застрекотал разом. 2) После ее желтого света в комнате синел холодный утренний сумрак. 3)Плотные утренние сумерки одевали все пространство вокруг серым сырым фоном, не позволяя отличить воду от неба. 4) Чуть только поредели лиловые утренние сумерки.

СМЕРКНУТЬСЯ, СМЕРКАТЬСЯ

"Только начало смеркаться". В безличной форме это, действительно, только вечерние сумерки, переход от света к темноте. Также возможно: Кругом всё смерклось (потемнело).

Answer (score 3):

Смеркаться - значит, темнеть. Соответственно, это явление может происходить только вечером.

Сумерки - это время суток между темнотой и светом, они могут быть утренними и вечерними.

Comment: >это явление может происходить только вечером. Сумерки - это время суток между темнотой и светом, они могут быть утренними и вечерними.

@Элен, нет ли тут какого-то противоречия в Вашем ответе?

Comment: @Nikolja, противоречий нет, тут два разных абзаца, но из-за неумения пользоваться сайтовым редактором, всё слилось в сплошной текст.

@Элен, чтобы разделить текст на абзацы нужно или два раза нажать энтер, тогда между абзацами будет полоса-пробел, или два пробела и энтер, тогда начнёте с отступом, но с новой строчки. Последний способ лучше всего подходит для оформления стихов, первый - для деления текста.

Comment: Да я и не стремилась разделить на абзацы. И не очень понимаю, почему нельзя сплошным текстом ответить (хотя соглашусь, что так лучше). И противоречия не вижу. И объясните, пожалуйста, в чём оно. 
         Спасибо.